# C++ Avoiding library linking

Tags: c++, class-library, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I currently have a c++ setup like the following

```
class FlowController
{
   public:
    //...
   private:
       cntrl::OneWayValve _intake;
}
```

As you can see i'm using a cntrl::OneWayValve instance within my class. The Valve class resides in another library which i link with at compile time. The cntrl::OneWayValve has a cntrl::Value within its implementation like so.

```
class OneWayValve
{
   public:
    //...
   private:
       cntrl::Valve _valve;
}
```

And as before the cntrl::Valve resides in a different library for reasons you'll have to ask the previous developer about.

Now when i compile my FlowController class i'm required to link with the OneWayValve library and the cntrl::Valve library as well.

My question:
Is it possible to only link with the cntrl::OneWayValve library at compile time?

Forward declaration?
Static libraries (really don't want to do this tho)?
Another alternative?

Basically i don't want to know that its using a cntrl::Valve internally, its none of my business.

Note: apologies the OS is Unix.

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Compiling and linking is somewhat different on different operating systems. What do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is make your Valve library part of your OneWayValve library using a tool called a librarian. I don't know what OS/compiler you are using so I'm going to describe how do it using Visual Studio since that's the only system I've actually done this with (unless you want to count CP/M + LIB-80 :-)

If you bring up the Tools|Options dialog for you OneWayValve project and select Configuration Properties|Librarian|Additional Dependencies, you can put a reference to your Valve library in the Additional Dependencies setting. This will cause OneWayValve.lib to contain any objects that it references from Valve.lib.

Comment: Cheers GNU libtool would appear to have what i need. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, the `OneWayValve` isn't very well designed. Not only you need to link to both libraries, but you will also have to recompile both the `OneWayValve` library and your code if the `Valve` class changes.

Comment: How do you know OneWayValve isn't very well designed? I see only dots and one private member.

Comment: @VJo The private member is the bad design reason.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Why? I agree that using the pimpl idiom is better, but there is nothing wrong with having private members.

Comment: @VJo It is if the definitions of those members are in a different library and the class on the library interface.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Nothing wrong with that. Dynamically link to that library, and the problem is solved.

Comment: @VJo What problem is solved? The problem is that if the bottom library changes, this change will have to be manually propagated (by recompiling the code) through all the dependencies up to the end program.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Ok, I understand. As I said, using the pimpl idiom would be better, and would prevent the recompilation from occurring if more members are added. But if a class signature changes, recompilation would be required - linking or not linking the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining all methods of OneWayValve and Valve in their headers as inline. Then you don't need to link to the library.

But if it was designed that way, then what problems are linking to this library causing? Nothing wrong with dynamically linking a library.

Comment: I would prefer not to know the internals of the OneWayValve class, Thats all.

Comment: @Ben In that case, look for pimpl idiom. I am sure you will get million hits on google.

Comment: Yep thank you i'm looking down that road the now. Thanks everyone for your help much appreciated.